# Can I hide an image path on asp.net page without http Handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, hide, hotlinking

I have many static images under a directory in my site structure, and I'm not concerned with hotlinking or copy-protecting the images. For a myriad of reasons, what I need to do is not show the image path on the site (or show a fake one).

Is there any way to do this without resorting to an http handler or a worker asp.net page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [URL Rewritting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx). Doing it yourself would require you to implement a custom handler but there are third party options already available you could try.

I would guess however that a simple http handler implemented as an ASHX endpoint would probably be the easiest option.

Comment: Another option would be URL routing (but only if .NET4 can be used): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: @Josh and @Luke: Not exactly what I wanted right now, but very good references that will definitely come in handy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Campos, I figured but that's the best I can come up with:-) Good luck if you find a simpler method let us know please

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic [ASHX handler](http://dotnetperls.com/ashx-handler) for this.

Comment: The question says "without resorting to an http handler".

Comment: That's true! But I was wondering if there was a simpler, more straight way of doing this.